# Sens de "Si, à son défaut ..."

Tags: sens

De [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_d%C3%A9faut_de):

> Si, à son défaut, je puis vous être utile, disposez de moi.

Je ne comprends pas le sens de cette phrase. À quoi se réfère “son” ici?

Par contre, je comprends bien le sens des autres exemples.

> À défaut de vin, nous boirons de l’eau.

Ça veut dire que nous boirons de l’eau car nous n'avons pas de vin. Mais le premier exemple n'est toujours pas clair pour moi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sans contexte, il est impossible de savoir exactement à quoi (ou plutôt à qui) *son défaut* fait référence.

On trouve cette phrase dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie française de 1835 et son style est désuet. On peut la comprendre comme ceci:

> Si la personne en question n'est pas en mesure de vous aider, je suis moi-même à votre entière disposition (pour le faire).

Answer (score 0):

Comme on le laisse entendre dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/29205), cet exemple est disparu du dictionnaire de l'Académie française en 2001 (note-t-on au LBU14 § 1038 R3), c'est-à-dire qu'il n'apparaît pas à la 9<sup>e</sup> édition, et je trouve personnellement sa formulation avec *à son défaut* plutôt opaque. Au *Bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>, 2011, § 1038), après avoir présenté les principales *locutions prépositives* (§ 1037), on se demande à quelles conditions des syntagmes formés d'une *préposition* suivie d'un *article défini* puis d'un *nom* et enfin de la préposition *de* sont considérés comme étant des locutions prépositives. Ce à quoi on répond *a contrario* en discutant de cas où l'on hésite à les qualifier de la sorte, dont celui où la « séquence *de* + pronom personnel régime peut être remplacée par le déterminant possessif » (LBU14), et on donne l'exemple en question avec *à son défaut* (on a aussi *à mon insu, à son endroit, à mon sujet, à mes dépens, à mon égard, à leur détriment, de ma part, à son endroit* etc., certainement moins inusités). Et donc incidemment on hésiterait à qualifier *à [défaut](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9faut) de (lui)*, qu'on comprend plus aisément à mon avis comme *en l'absence de celui-ci/celle-ci*, *en son absence*, ou *sans lui/elle*, et davantage encore quand on reformule comme on l'a fait ailleurs, de locution prépositive...

---

Je crois que le possessif *son* sert à exprimer *de qui* c'est le *défaut* (l'absence) pour ainsi dire : l'absence de cette personne, son défaut (son absence).